# Why can't I directly downvote on low quality post queue?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, low-quality-posts

I just saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14811358) from a new user, which was flagged low quality, but not downvoted.

Let me quote that (it was about the `f` float suffix in C++):

> try 1024*f, in c++,computer cannot recognize 1024f=1024*f.

It's a lot worse than "I have this problem too", or "restart pycharm and it will work", which are useless but not *wrong* at least.

So I took the time to navigate to the answer to downvote it to indicate that it's clearly wrong for future readers.

But why can't I directly downvote (or upvote, in some cases, since the short answer was a good one)? That would save a lot of time.

(I'm aware that not all review queues - close votes especially - should have this feature, but the "late answers from new users" has it for instance, low quality posts definitely deserves it too).

EDIT: seems like it's a cross-site duplicate: [Why is voting removed from new review system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

Comment: The general idea of a specific queue is to focus on *one* problem. In the case of the LQ queue this is: should the post be deleted or not.

Comment: at least the meta post attracted attention on the answer and a mod deleted it ! good.

Comment: @rene: you can also edit it (but it very unlikely, I never found an opportunity to edit so it was better, unless I add some of my personal technical knowledge, which would deviate the post).

Comment: *"The general idea of a specific queue is to focus on one problem. In the case of the LQ queue this is: should the post be deleted or not."* Yup, this one should be deleted. Glad to see Bhargav already handled it. You could not edit it to be correct without completely rewriting it, which everyone seems to agree is inappropriate. That means "unsalvageable", which means "delete".

Comment: @CodyGray what I forgot to mention is that I can only vote to delete. What if it is not deleted after all, and still has a neutral score? Well, the manual way works so I'll do that. It may not be useful on a daily basis.

Comment: If you like reviewing possibly problematic new answers to old questions, there is a chat bot named [Natty](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6817005) which monitors new answers to old questions applying heuristics and other filters to each post, and posts links (and other important information) to answers which have a high likelihood of being problematic in [SOBotics](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics).

Comment: If you really want this, you can install [this userscript](https://github.com/Undo1/FlagFromReview/blob/master/flagfromreview.user.js). It's name is "Flag from Review", but it even adds a "downvote" button in the LQP queue. It isn't like a normal vote down button, but a link type button under where you normally see "link" in the right hand side.