# Are super short answers really Not an Answer (NAA)?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

According to my recent experiences in the Low Quality Posts (LQP) queues, a *lot* of valid answers are getting deleted just for being too short, or more precisely, "*looks like*" a comment. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361924/5958455) is one (and [its review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18577233)):

The question is about configuring environment variables for Go in Bash, and this is a valid answer (I don't know Go but I know Bash):

> Add these commands to the `~/.bashrc`

That's just an example and there are a lot more. I wonder what LQP is supposed to do against such answers.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18628549)'s another example:

> You need a 64 bit version of Python.

The full answer is as short as it currently is: Use a 64-bit Python and the problem's gone.

Comment: IIRC, the system will put things in the queue that it thinks aren't answers and sometimes there are false positives, like code-only answers. If it answers the question, then it's an answer. If it didn't meet a length requirement then it wouldn't have let the user post it in the first place.

Comment: Add explanations why that particular solution applies to the problem? I mean, there's an edit button in the queue, for something it should be useful, no?

Comment: You state that this is a valid answer, yet you are one of the users who reviewed it as "Recommend Deletion". If you feel it's valid, why did you "Recommend Deletion"?

Comment: @Makyen I picked a bad example. That very answer won't benefit much if not further expanded.

Comment: @BSMP For code-only answers I add a comment from my SEAutoReviewComments, and choose "OK" or "Delete" depending on code quality.

Comment: Have I misunderstood what the LQP queue is for?

Comment: @Braiam The edit button isn't used to add extra explanation for the author. He should do it himself.

Comment: @iBug "Edit if you can fix all the problems with this answer" lacking explanation is a problem.

Comment: @BSMP: Nobody knows what the LQP queue is for.

Comment: @iBug The review queue isn't there to judge the quality of answers and delete those that you think don't do a good enough job.  It's there to delete answers that *aren't answers*.  If you think an answer is a bad answer, downvote it.  Don't abuse your privilege to delete an answer *that you know is an answer*.

Comment: Might some of them have been [automatically converted to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/364344)?

Comment: @Servy Of course bad answers should be deleted, if the reviewer has enough domain knowledge to tell that the answer holds _no benefit to mankind what-so-ever_. To not delete it is to abuse your privilege to user-moderate SO, a site dedicated to high quality technical Q&A.

Comment: @Lundin The design of the system is that if someone feels that, after judging an answer's technical merit, it's not useful, the tool available to them to express it is to downvote it.  Deleting is not designed to be a tool for judging the technical merits of a post.  Saying that it's okay *when the rules of the site are explicit about what the valid deletion reasons are, and "I don't think the post is technically correct" is not one of them, then no, you *can't* assert that it's okay to delete a post because you think it's not useful.  The tool you have to judge the quality of posts is voting.

Comment: @Servy No, none of that matters. If a post is complete crap and you are qualified enough to tell, go ahead and delete it. If some rule says that we must preserve crap just for the sake of keeping crap-huggers on meta happy, then that rule obviously needs to be re-written. The idea behind community moderation is that _we_ dictate the rules. So it is really just as simple as: does the majority of SO think that crap should be deleted? If so (I suspect this is the case), then delete it. All we should care about quality of the technical content.

Comment: @Lundin If you want to propose a change to a rule then *go ahead and propose a change*.  But telling people that the rules are **the complete opposite of what they are** is unacceptable.  That you don't care about the rules doesn't give you the right to ignore them and pretend they don't exist, or worse still, *lie to other people about what they are*.  If you want the rules changed then *convince the community that they should be changed*.  If the community consensus supports you, then you should have no problem doing that.

Comment: Given how bad so many reviewers are at determining if an answer even *is an answer at all*, I for one don't trust very few users with no demonstrated expertise in the field and very little experience in the site to accurately judge posts on their technical merit well enough to determine that the post is *so* bad that it should be deleted.  If they personally feel that it's not a useful post they already have the right to reflect that.  That *doesn't* mean they have the right to prevent everyone else from reflecting their own opinions.

Comment: @Servy The [rules here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) say _"Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted."_. Not just _can_ but _should_ be deleted. The [rules here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) say _"Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators."_ Everything I have said is in line with the current rules.

Comment: @Lundin But you're not suggesting deleting closed questions that aren't of lasting value.  You're suggesting that answers be deleted by a system in place to delete posts that  *aren't even answers* based on their technical merit.  So again, where's the rule that in the queue for deleting posts that *aren't even answers* users should be judging posts on their technical merit and deleting *answers to the question* that they don't think are useful.  Note how I didn't say that all deletion in all situations was bad, just that *this particular situation* isn't one where deletion isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Servy Here you go. https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers. "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:" /--/ "not even a partial answer to the actual question". So if I ask how to print hello world in Java and someone answers "you must feed oats to the pony", I can go ahead and delete the answer, since it is not even a partial answer to the actual question.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, answers that *are not even an attempt to answer the question* can be deleted.  Notice how I said that in my previous comment.  The queue *exists* to delete answers that *aren't even attempts to answer the question*.  But it *doesn't* exist to delete answers that the reviewer feels isn't a *useful* answer based on its technical merits, so long as it is an an answer.  As for your example, I cover that case in detail in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362237/).  It is indeed not an attempt to answer the question, but a mod flag would be preferable to NAA there.

Comment: I asked [a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311136/does-it-matter-that-short-answers-are-often-mistaken-for-comments) a couple of years ago, which was similar (closed as a duplicate, in fact) to [another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers) a couple of years before that.

Answer (score 30):

At the very least, answers like these could be vastly improved with some additional explanation.

Instead of just saying "Do XYZ." (which might indeed be the correct thing to do), a good answer would be closer to "You're doing ABC, which causes DEF to happen. You want XYZ instead, which causes blah blah blah..."

In the answer you linked, an explanation about what `.bashrc` is would be helpful, along with an explanation of why the user is seeing the behavior they're seeing.

Too often I see answers which are just a single line of code, which again might be a solution to the problem. But without any explanation, I consider these low quality answers.

See also: [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/294611)

Comment: That's why I picked "Recomd Del" for this very answer.

Comment: You're right that they're often low quality when we're talking about actual program code, but is it really necessary to explain what .bashrc is when you can easily research that yourself in minutes? Besides, if you don't know about it then you very likely have a much bigger problem: you don't know how your OS shell environment works and need to go learn the basics of working with said shell environment. That's not something that a StackOverflow answer can or should help you with, it's too big of a you-problem.

Comment: @Kevin You may consider it a low quality answer, but should it be deleted, or add a comment requesting more info and "Looks OK"?

Comment: @CalvT븃 why not edit? Edit is there for "fixing all the problems" with the post. Lacking information is a problem.

Comment: @Braiam because I don't necessarily know enough about that technology to add the correct information.

Comment: @CalvT븃 [citation needed].

Comment: @Braiam See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305990/350567): *Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author. If only the author can fix the question, the correct option is "Unsalvageable".* Although it's for questions, the same applies to answers, too.

Comment: @iBug no, because unlike questions, answers are usually framed in a specific context: answering the question. You can ask any question, but not post any answer to any question. They are orthogonal. Questions on the other hand doesn't need context, it construct the context by itself. You can't provide context for a question since you don't know the specific situation that surrounds the issue, it's unaccessible without the asker. Meanwhile you can easily explain how an answer works because all the context is provided and accessible to you.

Comment: @Braiam One is not obligated to contribute to other's answers.

Comment: @iBug then, allow others to do so and skip. What's so hard with simply allowing others to do so? You don't use the power yet want others to not use it?

Comment: @Braiam: I agree that the context is there and could be edited into the answer. But is that useful? If all the context is already provided, does it really help to duplicate that context by editing it into the answer? The answer builds on the question and the usual user will be aware of the question when reading the answer.

Comment: @sth I'm confused, what context are you talking about? The context I'm talking about is that every answer has the question as context, the thing that would be edited into the answer is the explanation of how the answer fits into the context.

Answer (score 30):

> Are super short answers really NAA?

Your question answers itself.  That you've defined them as *answers* means that they're not "Not An Answer".  Not An Answer is for things that *aren't answers*.  Note that there isn't anything in the flag description or any of the deletion reasons in there for posts that answer the question but that are short, instead they're about whether or not they attempt to answer the question, or if they are one of a few things (i.e. requests for information) that *aren't even answers*.

If you think that an answer isn't a *good* answer, you're more than welcome to downvote it and/or comment on it to indicate how it could be improved.

Falsely claiming that it's not an answer *when you know that it's an answer* is unacceptable.

Comment: but the queue doesn't allow to downvote directly. so people click on "delete" when the answer is bad.

Comment: You're parsing words too finely, I think.  Should iBug instead say "Are super short posts purporting to be answers really NAA"?  Maybe, but it's not our general practice, and it's not useful to mince words over that usage.  I agree, though, that there is a difference between a post that falsely purports to be an answer on one hand, and a post that plausibly purports to be an answer but isn't a good one on the other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Considering the post then goes on to describe answers that are answering the question, but that are just short, rather than answers that aren't even trying to answer the question, and whose length is irrelevant, I fail to see how anything in my answer is misinterpreting the question.  What about the question leads  you to believe that this is actually asking about answers that are asking clarifying questions of the question author, asking new questions, or is any other type of post that would merit a NAA flag?

Comment: @Servy, I am objecting to your "That you've defined them as answers means that they're not 'Not An Answer'."  He is certainly concerned about posts purporting to be answers that indeed do answer the question, however poorly, but he does not define those posts as falling into that category by calling them "answers".  Aside from the fact that it is our common usage to refer to all posts purporting to be answers as "answers", he distinguishes those posts from other "answers" as "just [] being too short".  So no, his question does not answer itself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you saw, "Is this answer to the question NAA?" out of context, you'd be right that it's not clear if "this answer" means that it's an answer to the question, or if it's something posted as an answer that's not.  But, again, *the question goes on to say that it's an answer, and that it's answering the question*.  Thus they have very specifically demonstrated that they *don't* mean, "this was posted as an answer", but that they mean, "this is actually an answer to the question".  They have *defined* the post as being an answer to the question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's not perfect but there is a link to the answer from the queue. I use it all the time to down-vote crap "answers" that I would say should also be deleted.

Comment: I know. What I mean is: since there are no DV/UV buttons, people tend to "delete" instead, because they think they _have_ to, where downvoting would be enough. I posted a question on that "why can't I downvote on the LQ queue".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I see. That would be a good addition to the queue, though, I also think the rules for deleting should be loosened. Do you have a link for that question? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: sorry I was just lazy: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341088/why-cant-i-directly-downvote-on-low-quality-post-queue

Answer (score 12):

I'd say there are two questions here.

### Is this a good answer

I think we [all agree this could be improved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362355/542251) a lot. So no, it's not a good answer

### But is it an attempt to answer?

IMO yes. This does **attempt** to answer the question. Only answers that meet the various deleting criteria should actually be deleted. So does this question meet any of these:
[image]

You could argue this is a "commentary" but that seems to be pushing it IMO. Read the definition carefully:

> This is commentary on another post, not an answer....

so, is this commenting on another post? I don't think so.

If I reviewed this, I'd vote **OK**. I'd also possibly downvote and or add a comment saying this needs better clarification. Or if possible edit the answer to clarify, not sure that applies here though...

Comment: LQRQ is for dealing with low quality post, some merit deletion some merit edition. No queue is binary, all of them offer more than 2 options to deal with the review.

Comment: Yes editing is an option. If possible. I can't see how you could really edit the answer here though?

Comment: bashrc is interpreted by bash as function, commands, operands, etc. by bash, it's just describing what they do to obtain the result. (in other words, translating from programming to english)

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes an answer that's short, sweet, and to-the-point is exactly what is required. The context of the question itself needs to be considered.

Answer (score 7):

- Does it answer the question correctly? If so, then it is a valid answer no matter length. Done.
- Does it attempt to answer the question, but is incorrect or bad? If so, down vote, leave a comment etc. If the answer is completely horrible, you can flag for "very low quality" or cast a delete vote.
- Does it not attempt to answer the question at all? Then it is not an answer. Flag for "not an answer".

Answer (score 5):

This comes up perennially in different forms and context, but the guidance that I give to folks since being elected in 2011 hasn't changed.

If it's a *good faith* attempt to directly address the question, ***it's an answer***.

That doesn't make it:

- Correct
- Optimal
- Not overly laconic
- Jell-O, or a pudding pop

.. but it *is* an answer. Downvote it if you want, high-rep users can even vote to delete it if the quality is so bad that it's embarrassing, but a group of people taking what *was* a good faith attempt at answering a question and insisting that it wasn't an answer at all is essentially [gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting) the person that wrote it, which isn't a very nice way to welcome them. This is a common source of friction for very new users.

It's okay to tell people that while we appreciate the effort, a little more is needed in order for their contribution to be lasting. That's kind of brutal when you consider that it's a completely volunteer effort that runs entirely off the spare cycles that folks can give, but it's honest, and lets people know that they're *probably* in the right place if quality and becoming a better communicator is what they're after.

Saying *hey, you didn't even answer the question* is like saying *you didn't type anything at all* or, *you must [love turtles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y)*.

Being more direct by saying *okay, this is a great start, but you have to flesh it out a bit if you want it to last* is a lot more productive than looking at a circle someone made and screaming at them that it's not round - all you're going to do is give them quite a jolt and likely get into an argument. It's not round *enough* is quite a bit different, and looks for a different kind of response :)

When it comes to ultimately deciding what content folks vote to delete, the distinction starts to lose meaning (stuff gets deleted for a variety of reasons, it's either in the 'keep' or 'pitch' pile at that point). But initially, it's pretty important to keep that distinction, and help keep the grumbling that we're a bunch of deletionist jerks down a bit :)

Comment: "to **directly address the** question" and that's where most people lose their bearings, because the post doesn't attempt to answer the "damn question" at all. That's enough grounds for me to delete any answer, irrespectively the length of the answer.

Comment: I gotta put that case back in where simply typing "42" with no additional characters bypassed all quality and length filters.

Comment: That would be interesting, to say the least. Now, remember that I'm actually more in the side of ["fix the post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362328/are-super-short-answers-really-not-an-answer-naa#comment551066_362355), that most people reject any attempt to fix the post by editing, that's another problem SE needs to address.

Answer (score 4):

No, not necessarily.

<sub>But IMO they often deserve downvotes ;)</sub>

Comment: This is commentary on another post, not an answer ;)

Comment: I get conflicted with these answers. I love the fact that it willingly proves the point by being a low quality answer that I should downvote :) I am going to make the decision once and for all: on meta these get an upvote from me. Fun is good.

Comment: I certainly agree. Though, fun apart (which is *probably* fine and *might* be upvoted on meta), I consider my answer an example deserving downvoting, while [Mark Ransom's one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362376/479251) subtly summarize answer & argumentation, and would deserve (at least some) upvote for visibility and being useful. (IMHO)